# Copy one cell value to all column based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server

basically, I have one table and I want to copy cell value in a column named "A" and have id = 5 to another column which is named "B". But I want only this cell to fill my "B" column like if this cell has value "s7", so I want my all "B" column cells have "s7"

I tried something like:

`UPDATE service SET PathNameAr = NameAr WHERE id ='430`, but it just fill only one cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're only setting the column in the row with an id of 430. If you want it to apply to all rows, try without the where clause - so just `UPDATE service SET PathNameAr = NameAr`. Are you trying to get the "s7" value from the row with ID of 430, and set all other NameAr columns in all rows to that value? If so, you'd want to do this:

```
UPDATE service SET PathNameAr = (SELECT NameAr FROM service WHERE id=430)
```

This will get the value of the `NameAr` column from the row with id 430, and will set all `PathNameAr` columns equal to that value.